# how to set condition in String Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am looping Text Field hundreds times

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

my label Text is look like this `labelText: '${i + 1}',`

I want to set Condition if `i` is below 10 then add extra `0` before number

I did try with like this

```
'${i < 10 ? "0"i + 1 : i + 1}',
```

getting error Expected to Find '}'

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) print(i.toString().padLeft(2, '0'));` or in your case: `labelText: i.toString().padLeft(2, '0')`

Comment: need to increase by 1

Comment: @JahidulIslam yes, need to increase by 1: `labelText: (i + 1).toString().padLeft(2, '0')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a another solution by using String's padLeft method.

[image]

```
  for (var i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
    print(i.toString().padLeft(2, '0'));
  }
```

Comment: Oops, there is a same solution by pskink.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    print('${i+1 < 10 ? "0${i + 1}" : i + 1}');
  }
```